# Convert all the files to another format iteratively

Tags: bash

I want to convert all the `.hic` files to `.mcool` format. My code currently convert files from `abc.hic` to `abc.hic.mcool` but I want it to be `abc.mcool`.

```
for id in *.hic; 
do hic2cool convert $id ${id%.}.mcool; 
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Remove matching suffix pattern" needs the whole pattern to remove, not just its starting character.

```
#! /bin/bash
for id in *.hic ; do
    hic2cool convert "$id" "${id%.hic}".mcool; 
done
```

I also added double quotes around the variables to make it work even if the file names contain whitespace.